# Rapidly switching on and off a 12v power supply, bad idea?

Tags: power-supply, power, mains

I was just wondering if this would be a bad idea, the power supply is connected to the mains power and would only undergo this at a max of 10 minutes at a time.

would this cause any damage to the power supply or cause any problems with my mains power?

Comment: That depends on the power supply, and what you're powering, neither of which you've  told us anything about. Why would you turn it on and off at the mains, though, instead of switching its output?

Comment: Without knowing the circuit being switched it would be impossible to say for certain. However, transient pulses have a nasty habit of destroying electronic circuits.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fuse will die in short order. Everything else will probably be okay, but it's additional stress that will tend to shorten the life of the rectifiers and main filter capacitors in particular. [Schurter](http://www.schurter.ca/content/download/194051/5552460/file/Guide_to_Fuse_Selection.pdf) says:

> Inrush Current Peak
>
> Continuous exposure to pulses of high current could prematurely age the fuse.
>   The number of pulses the fuse would be exposed to in the application should also be considered when choosing a fuse.

[image]

If the PSU uses a circuit breaker rather than a fuse and your switching frequency is low enough that the breaker has a chance to cool, it may be okay, at least in the short term. 10 minutes 'off time' is long enough that any inrush protection thermistors should have a chance to reasonably cool down.

Very short off times (seconds) could be close to worst-case and may damage parts other than the fuse relatively fast, as well as causing thermal cycling.